# how to use boost or weight in more_like_this

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following Elastic Query,

```
   more_like_it_match = {
        "min_score": 5,
        "query":
            {"filtered": {
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": {
                            "more_like_this": {
                                "fields": ["title","desc","cat_id","user_id"],
                                "like": {
                                    "doc": {
                                        "title": item["title"],
                                        "desc": item["desc"],
                                        "cat_id": item["cat_id"],
                                        "user_id": item["user_id"],
                                    },
                                },
                                "min_term_freq": 1,
                                "max_query_terms": 100,
                                "min_doc_freq": 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "filter": {
                    "not": {
                        "term": {
                            "id": item["id"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

it works correctly but I'm looking for a solution that I could set boost or weight for each one of the fields, as an example I want to say to Elastics *Title* field matching is three-time more important than *Category Field*, is there any way to achieve it?

**note:** I've found the following query as the solution but it not what I'm looking for.

```
 {
        "min_score" : 5,
        "query": {
            "dis_max": {
               "queries": [
                   {
                    "more_like_this" : {
                        "fields" : ["title"],
                        "like_text" : item["title"],
                        "min_term_freq" : 1,
                        "max_query_terms" : 100,
                        "boost": 100
                    }
                   },
                   {
                    "more_like_this" : {
                        "fields" : ["desc"],
                        "like_text" : item["desc"],
                        "min_term_freq" : 1,
                        "max_query_terms" : 100,
                        "boost": 100,
                    }
                   }
                ]
            }
        },
        "filter":{
            "not":{
                "term" :{
                    "id": item["id"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html

> Dis Max Queryedit
>   A query that generates the union of documents produced by its subqueries, and that scores each document with the maximum score for that document as produced by any subquery, plus a tie breaking increment for any additional matching subqueries.
>
> This is useful when searching for a word in multiple fields with different boost factors (so that the fields cannot be combined equivalently into a single search field). We want the primary score to be the one associated with the highest boost, not the sum of the field scores (as Boolean Query would give). If the query is "albino elephant" this ensures that "albino" matching one field and "elephant" matching another gets a higher score than "albino" matching both fields. To get this result, use both Boolean Query and DisjunctionMax Query: for each term a DisjunctionMaxQuery searches for it in each field, while the set of these DisjunctionMaxQuery’s is combined into a BooleanQuery.